# Как узнать версию App проги?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

После изменения версии проги мне нужно скинуть ее сетап на дефолтный. Как проверить что версия проги изменилась ?

- Bild

  > [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
  > infoDictionary]
  > objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
- Version

  > [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
  > infoDictionary]
  > objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить текущую версию можно так:

```
- (NSString *)appNameAndVersionNumberDisplayString {
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    return minorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
}
```

Соответственно тебе остается только хранить предыдущую версию и при входе проверять на изменение.